# fastify serve angular6 application

Tags: node.js, angular, fastify

i have a question.
I have an angular6 application and a back-end with fastify.
Fastify serve application so:

```
fastify.use(['/'], serveStatic(path.join(__dirname + '/../dist/')));
```

in the dist folder there is the angular build.

start my application with node index.js command

on localhost:3000/ fastify serve the application, but when i try to refresh localhost:3000/user fastify respond 404 Not Found! Because he search path /user in his API but /user is an angular route.

How can I solve this malfunction?

Answer (score 0):

You should separate all your api routes with some prefix, for example `/api`. Then you can redirect all requests with URL not starting with `/api` to Angular index file - because that's frontend routes.